# Converting CUDA .cu file to PTX file

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cuda, ptx

I am having problem converting `.cu` to `.ptx`. I am using `nvcc` as follows:

> "C:\ Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\nvcc" -ptx -ccbin "C:\ Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin" -o foo.ptx foo.cu

The following is displayed in return:

> ```
> foo.cu
> c1xx : fatal error C1083: cannot open source file: 'foo.cu': No such file or directory
> ```

`foo.cu` is located in the `\CUDA\v5.0\bin`.

Comment: In which folder are you running the command? This just means that `nvcc` cannot find your `foo.cu` file. Either run the command in the file's folder, or provide a full path to `nvcc`.

Comment: I am giving the full path in the command but you have edited my message.
> "C:\ Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.0\bin\nvcc" -ptx -ccbin "C:\ Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin" -o foo.ptx foo.cu

Comment: You are right. I gave the command from the said directory and it is now compiling. Its giving something like:
'tmpxft_00001100_000000000-5_foo.cudafe1.gpu' and
'tmpxft_00001100_000000000-10_foo.cudafe2.gpu'
But where do I find my foo.ptx? I cannot see it. Is something still wrong?

Comment: The `ptx` files are in the directory from which you launched `nvcc`. For instance, if I run the following command on Linux: `nvcc test.cu -ptx -o test.ptx`, I get `test.ptx` in the current directory.

Comment: No, not there. Is there any other non-commandline method?

Comment: Does the compilation work? If compilation fails, you will not get any `ptx` file, obviously.

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2010 to basically compile and run my `.cu` files. I need to convert them to `.ptx` to be able to use these gpu functions in the MATLAB code. Now, I have gone back and tried to generate the `.ptx` file by changing the custom build options of the VC project for `CUDA C/C++`. In there, I have allowed to keep the `pre-processed files` and enabled to `generate relocatable device code`. `.cu` and `.gpu` files are being output successfully but as it tries to generate the `.ptx` the following happens:

Comment: You should use http://pastebin.com/ to share long messages in the comment section.

Comment: Ben, thanks and sorry. Here is the [build output](http://pastebin.com/CbQhcxZD)

Comment: Could you also share the content of your `x64/Debug/TestingPTX.cu.obj.cu.ptx` file, or at least the beginning? You should have a `.version` and `.target` at the start of the file. I think these are actually not `ptx` files, since I don't see any `-ptx` option for `nvcc` in your build output.

Comment: No, I do not have a `.version` or `.target` in my TestingPTX.cu file. The C++ code for the given file can be seen at: [http://pastebin.com/f78v7ReM](http://pastebin.com/f78v7ReM)

Comment: So what is in the `.ptx` file then? By doing `nvcc -ptx testingptx.cu -o testingptx.ptx` with your code, I get http://pastebin.com/hQ6hBqcg.

Comment: That is the problem. In my case such commands are not working. What i get is [pastebin.com/nAZDgDth](http://pastebin.com/nAZDgDth)

Comment: You are using Windows so the compiler may expect some different things. You just need to make sure that the `-ptx` flag is used by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the `Project Properties` in Visual Studio 2010. In `CUDA C/C++`, in `Common` change the property `Keep Preprocessed Files` to `Yes(--keep)`. Build the project. You should be able to see the .ptx file in folder as `C:/Users/Mansoor/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/Testing_PTX/x64/Debug` depending on the configuration (x32 or x64). If your `.cu` filename was `TestingPTX.cu` then the filename for PTX file would be `TestingPTX.compute_xx.ptx` where `xx` is the compute capability defined in your project properties. For multiple compute capability options there will be a dedicated `.ptx` file. The content of a typical PTX file can be seen at [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/zuz0FHGq)
It is very straight forward but took me quite some time to figure out because there is not much material over the internet regarding generation of .ptx within the Visual Studio environment. Hope it will help the newbies like me.